# Creating a Logger

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, log4net

It's not really a coding problem, but i'm after some feedback from the community regarding some issues that I'm having, while developing a new Logger implementation.

## Background

our ASP.NET Application originally worked with log4net. While log4net is a great logging tool, it does not suit our needs and in some cases it even causes problems for our application by the way the logging is done. We currently are implementing our own logging system that is mimicing some behavior of log4net, but also tailored to suit our needs. I'm not here to discuss about the usage of log4net or how to config it.

## System

Currently we have a system that's beeing developed. The system has a logger class, which is a Singleton (*design flaw, I know...*) and this class has a collection of **IReporter** objects.

Everytime the application calls **Logger.Instance.Log(message)** the logger will direct these messages to every **IReporter** inside the queue, and the reporters have the responsibility of logging the message in their destination/storage/whatever.

Currently we've chosen that each **IReporter** has a backgroundthread and a message queue to process the messages at their own speed. The danger here is that when the app dies suddenly we could lose some of the messages.

Another approach we had in mind was to have a thread pool on the logger and let these threads run over the queue and then delegate the messages to the reporters.

**What I'm concerned about is the performance. We first implemented this using events in the logger, but the threads spawned went haywire fast when accessing  the file. So now with this approach we hope to limit the access to the resources**

What I'm lookign for is people who had similar situations and how they approached this issue.

Comment: Have you looked at NLog? http://nlog-project.org/

Comment: We're dealing with a commercial application, so open-source is not really an option atm

Comment: Won't help you immediately, but I strongly recommend looking at the source for NLog and Log4net.  They have gone to great lengths to make sure logging is performant.  Also, you might want to *disable logging except if it is configured in your app*, then you can turn it on in production when necessary.  This includes inserting `if` blocks before your trace statements, or putting your trace statements in delegates so even the string formatting code isn't run if logging is disabled.  Won't help the BG thread issue, but they solve that too (I just don't know how :)

Comment: Commercial + open source can be an option.  Your lawyers/managers just have to okay it.  Depends on the license (e.g. log4net is apache).  If your management bullheadedly says no, then I guess you're stuck on that front...

Comment: @NekoNova I would disagree, I have seen NLog used in large commercial applications succesfully before. It really depends on the policy of your company

Comment: log4net is very extensible, so rather than reinventing the wheel from scratch, you may be better to just fix the spokes you don't like--e.g., implement your own appenders etc with the behaviour you require.

Answer (score 2):

Did I understand it correctly, and all those processes access the same set of files? On Windows?

You shouldn't do that, as the OS will do some complex locking that will take time, or worse, depending on how you access the files, you can get a deadlock. It would be better to do all the logging on one single thread, and running the IReporters sequentialy.

If you are concerned that your software may die during a log operation, put the logger in another process, communicate by IPC. But are you sure you want to reinvent syslogd?

Comment: The goal is to have 1 reporter for each log file, especially to prevent multiple threads from accessing the specific log file and getting into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your design sounds an awful lot like Log4Net with a bunch of `FileAppender`s.  You should really reconsider your decision, unless there are requirements on you that you haven't shared.  Log4Net has a **lot** more use in the field than your logger ever will, and it's had lots of bugs and performance issues already shaken out of it.